# Admitir letras y espacios en Python

Tags: python

Tengo un programa que registra nombre y apellido y tengo un filtro para que no se admitan caracteres que no sean letras, pero el espacio al no ser una letra no la admite y no puedo poner el apellido.

¿Alguien sabe como puedo admitir los espacios?

He visto la sentencia `S.isspace()`, pero no le veo utilidad ya que sólo devuelve `True` si todo el string tiene espacios.

Código:

```python
nmyap1 = (input("MESA 1: Ingresa nombre y apellido de 1era persona: "))
while (len(nmyap1)>20) or (not (nmyap1.isalpha())):
    nmyap1 = (input("Demasiados car. (max 20) o car. invalido, ingrese otra vez: "))
```

Answer (score 2):

`str.isspace()` devuelve `True` para todo tipo de separadores en blanco, como espacios o tabuladores. Si sólo quieres permitir espacios puedes utilizar una comprobación del tipo:

```
while (len(nmyap1)>20) or (not (all(c.isalpha() or c==' ' for c in nmyap1))):
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternativamente se puede utilizar una expresión regular para validar el los caracteres y el largo utilizando [re.fullmatch()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.fullmatch).

**Código:**

```python
import re

nmyap1 = input("MESA 1: Ingresa nombre y apellido de 1era persona: ")
while (not re.fullmatch(r"[A-Za-z ]{1,20}", nmyap1)):
    nmyap1 = input("\nDemasiados car. (max 20) o car. invalido, ingrese otra vez: ")
```

Demo: http://ideone.com/XK5sul

**Descripción:**

[`re.fullmatch()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.fullmatch) utiliza una expresión regular para probar si coincide con todo un texto. La función devuelve un objeto `Match`si coincide o `None` si no coincide (que se evalúa como `False`).

La expresión regular `[A-Za-z ]{1,20}` coincide exclusivamente con entre 1 y 20 letras o espacios. Al negar el resultado con `not`, se ejecuta el bucle cuando no coincida.

Para permitir caracteres en español, se puede reemplazar por la expresión regular:

```
[A-Za-zÁÉÍÓÚÜÑáéíóúüñ ]{1,20}
```